# Creating new column in dataframe using data from another dataframe meeting certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python/coding, so forgive me if I'm making a silly error. I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe, portfolio, using data (prices) from another dataframe, stock_data, based on where the date and ticker symbol in the two dataframes match. The two dataframes have different dimensions.

This is what I've tried:

```
portfolio['Price'] = stock_data[(stock_data['Date']== portfolio['Date'])& (stock_data['ticker']==(portfolio['Ticker']))]['Adj Close']
```

I've also tried it with a for loop but I still get the following error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you give the condition in `stock_data`, the number of records that satisfy the condition is lesser or greater than the number of records in `portfolio`. If you check the length of both you would get to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) exists precisely for this purpose.

```py
portfolio.merge(stock_data[['Date', 'ticker', 'Adj Close']], 
                how='inner', 
                left_on=['Date', 'Ticker'], 
                right_on=['Date', 'ticker'])
portfolio.columns = list(portfolio.columns[:-1]).append('Price')  # rename last col
```